# Consistency in the color of groups in 'plotly' plots in R when making many plots

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), col2 = rnorm(12), col3 = runif(12), col4 = rep(c("Fred", "Bob"), each = 6))
df1_list <- split(df1, df1$col1)
```

I'm trying to make a separate plot for each list element and arrange them in the same figure:

```
lapply(df1_list, function (arg1) {
  plotly::plot_ly(arg1, x = ~col2, y = ~col3, color = ~col4) %>%
    layout(showlegend = T)
}) %>%
  subplot()
```

The problem is that the colors are not consistent across each plot. I'd like points representing `Fred` always to be the same color, and the same should go for points representing `Bob`.

Is there a way to ensure groups get the same color across all these plots?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a named color vector which assigns a color to each name like so:

```r
set.seed(123)

df1 <- data.frame(col1 = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4), 
                  col2 = rnorm(12), 
                  col3 = runif(12), 
                  col4 = rep(c("Fred", "Bob"), each = 6))
df1_list <- split(df1, df1$col1)

colors <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set2")[c(1, 3)]
names(colors) <- c("Fred", "Bob")

library(plotly)

lapply(df1_list, function (arg1) {
  plotly::plot_ly(arg1, x = ~col2, y = ~col3, color = ~col4, colors = colors) %>%
    layout(showlegend = T)
}) %>%
  subplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. What if I only want 'Fred' and 'Bob' to appear once in the legend?

Comment: Hm. The general approach to achieve that would be via `plotly(..., legendgroup = ~col4)` and then setting `showlegend=FALSE` for all expect one of the plots. See e.g. at the end of https://plotly.com/r/legend/ However, in your case that does not work. I can only guess that this is related to the fact that not all groups are present in each of your sub-datasets. So I'm afraid as of the moment I could not help you on that.